# TestCafe: How Do I Keep My Concurrent Test Runner Open?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

### Summary

I'm trying to set up two test runner files: One with serially performed tests, and one with concurrent. My concurrent test runner starts up fine, but it exists the test runner immediately after the first test file. How do I mitigate this?

### Code

```
    let testcafe = null;

    createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
        .then(tc => {
            testcafe = tc;
            const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

            return runner
                .src([
                    'tests/fixture1.js', //exits once these complete
                    'tests/fixture2.js',
                    'tests/fixture3.js,
                    'tests/fixture4.js
                ])
                .browsers(['chrome'])
                .concurrency(4)
                .run()
        })
        .then(failedCount => {
            testcafe.close();
            process.exit();

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            testcafe.close();
            process.exit(1);
        })
```

### Additional Details

As a tangent, it would be nice to know if there's a better way to configure tests in one file with some that should run concurrently and some that should run serially.

Comment: We didn't face any issue with concurrency and multiple files. Could you please share both your files? Also please specify how you're starting your tests.
Please also note that you can define multiple runners for a single TestCafe instance, so you can put them in one file. Please see the gist https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/c8cba98684f677d283992049f13967ae

Comment: @AlexKamaev Thank you. Seems to be fine after updating TestCafe to latest.